# Is feedback on questions about performance an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I just found this answer in a question about performance:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932477/5263291

which is not about the root cause of performance, but judging the method and the intent of the performance test, is it still an answer?

Comment: Yes - or at least an attempt to answer. But the question is pretty much bogus.